# Computer freezes when playing games on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Lenovo Z710 laptop that has two GPUs: an NVIDIA GeForce GT 745M and the Intel integrated graphics. When I don't have a second monitor hooked up to my laptop, games run without any issues; if I hook up the second monitor through VGA it runs fine until I start playing a game, and my computer freezes completely to the point where I have to force it to restart. It's never instant - sometimes it takes one hour for the freeze to happen - sometimes only 20 minutes.

It seems like the freeze happens only when I'm using GT745M GPU while second monitor is connected to laptop. GPU drivers are up to date and I don't know what else to do to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: From my understanding, if your laptop has a GPU all of the graphic processing is routed through it - so you wouldn't technically have an integrated option unless they are literally both showing up in your Device Manager; regardless - what are you doing on both monitors when the crashing occurs? do you have your game running across both? or do you have the game on one while you do other stuff on the other one?

Comment: I have the game on my second monitor opened, on laptop i have youtube opened where i watch videos while playing. Laptop can freeze if only game is opened or if youtube and game is opened.

Comment: @mael' Hybrid graphics. For light tasks the integrated Intel is used by default but if gaming then the Nvidia kicks in.

Comment: @davka Do you notice the laptop hotter than usual when it happens?